# Is this a php bug, or is something wrong with my timezone/PHP settings?

Tags: php, datetime, exception, timezone

The real, full contents of the file:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set(display_errors, 'on');

try {

    //$x = strtotime('blah');
    $x = new DateTime('lol');

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The DateTime constructor accepts a string, which should throw an exception if it can't parse it. This runs fine on my local machine but on one of my remote servers the exception is not caught ( and again, I *am* using try/catch and the SAME EXACT code ):

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct() [function.DateTime---construct]:
>   Failed to parse time string (lol) at
>   position 0 (l): The timezone could not
>   be found in the database' in
>   /var/www/html/site_com/rez/date.php:9
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/site_com/rez/date.php(9):
>   DateTime->__construct('lol') #1 {main}
>   thrown in
>   /var/www/html/site_com/rez/date.php on
>   line 9

Settings for remote server where the exception is not caught:

> PHP Version 5.2.5
>
> date date/time support    enabled
>   "Olson" Timezone Database Version
>     2007.9 Timezone Database    internal Default timezone   America/Chicago
>
> Directive Local Value Master Value
>   date.default_latitude 31.7667 31.7667
>   date.default_longitude    35.2333 35.2333
>   date.sunrise_zenith   90.583333   90.583333
>   date.sunset_zenith    90.583333   90.583333
>   date.timezone no value    no value

My local settings where it does work:

> PHP 5.2.10
>
> date date/time support    enabled
>   "Olson" Timezone Database Version
>     0.system Timezone Database  internal Default timezone   System/Localtime
>
> Directive Local Value Master Value
>   date.default_latitude 31.7667 31.7667
>   date.default_longitude    35.2333 35.2333
>   date.sunrise_zenith   90.583333   90.583333
>   date.sunset_zenith    90.583333   90.583333
>   date.timezone no value    no value

Locally, it catches the exception and prints the error out. The `date.timezone` on both is no value.

Perhaps it's just my internal system's timezones which are off? My local box is Ubuntu and my remote is CentOS, they're probably inconsistent but shouldn't PHP still catch the exception?

FYI I can't update PHP on the remote box since I don't have admin rights.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My bet is on a PHP bug. I know that PHP used to have issues with catching exceptions thrown in constructors, and that seems to be what's going on here.

Because it's a bug, your options are

1. Update the server's PHP version; you said this isn't an option
2. Use `strtotime()` to find the date or, if you need or want access to the object-oriented style of `DateTime`, catch the error with `strtotime()`

For example:

```
<?php

try {

    if (@strtotime($str) !== false) {
        $x = new DateTime($str);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Failed to parse string ({$str})");
    }

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You might even try extending the DateTime class, and overriding the constructor with the code above, except instead of new DateTime you would use parent::__construct(). Remember that the prototype has to be the same, so your construct should take two parameters (string $str, DateTimeZone $timezone = null). This has the added benefit of determining whether the __construct() uncatchable exception bug is the source of your problems.

Comment: Yeah I'm currently using strtotime and making sure it doesn't fail, then feeding it to the DateTime constructor - I'll try extending.

Comment: Can reproduce this in PHP 5.5.9ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the exact issue but try setting the time zone using this function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); // or whatever timezone
```

And see if this works.

Comment: The server that is not catching the exception already has one set (Default timezone America/Chicago).

Comment: yeah I already tried this before and it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: this is a weird problem then, let's see what is the solution for it then

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem, was able to fix with

```
date('date format', $str);
date("Y-m-d", $news->created);
```

Hope that helps someone.